# Из чего делают игры в Java (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, разработка-игр

[image: снимок ide]

Вот картинка. Какой пункт выбирать надо для создания Java игры?

Comment: игра случайно не для телефона нужна?

Comment: но мне нужна игра для компа, ну на телефон.
Но сначала для компа.

Comment: Однозначно сначало нужно будет выбрать Java Project. Ну а вообще знание языка Вам не помешало бы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вначале найдите подходящий движок для игры, определитесь будет 2D или 3d. Кстати, jmonkeyengine отличная штука, попробуйте ее. А вообще без обид, но вам рано заниматься подобными вещами, сначала подучите java.

Comment: Я видел видио, где было показано, что игра сделана в eclipse и она роботала!

Comment: Думаю Eclipse недооценивать не стоит.

Comment: "Я видел видео..." - пруфлинк или не было.

Comment: вот игра сделана в Escape http://u.to/x6gkAQ Я вот наподобе такой хочу сделать.

Comment: Затягивает :) Так а где видели-то, как делали? Вот как видели, так и сделайте.

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю не стоит писать так:

> в Java (Eclipse)

Java - это, всё-таки, язык

Eclipse - это, всё-таки, IDE

Comment: но взято с Java!

Comment: если с java, тогда и выбирайте "java project".

Comment: Спосибо!